# question about contractive and hereditary property

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is $T_B$ if each compact subset  is closed.

A topological space is called a US-space provided that each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

A topological property $\mathcal{R}$ is contractive if $(X,\tau)$ has property $\mathcal{R}$ and if $\tau^{\prime} \subset \tau$,
then (A, $\tau^{\prime}$) has property $\mathcal{R}$.

A topological space is called a C- C-space provided that  the  compact subsets  are precisely the closed sets.

> Is property C-C , US contractive,  hereditary?
>
> Is property $T_B$  contractive?

Comment: Please do not clutter the site with duplicates of your own questions. This is spam.